# Codeigniter web app is not working with the linux but here on windows is fine

Tags: php, codeigniter, centos

**Codeigniter web app is not working with the linux but here on windows is fine**

i have install wamp server on my windows and i set my application(codeigniter) there is working fine but here on linux(Centos) other php application are just woking fine but only 
this codeigniter app is not working

there there any pakage does it requires or ...

thanks

Comment: I use CodeIgniter in ubuntu and it works fine. What problem are you facing?

Comment: i am just geting white page no error noting

Comment: Is error reporting turned on? Even the index page is blank?

Comment: My experience the working in windows not on linux is usually a case sensitive vs case insensitive filesystem issue.

Comment: Check this out, [Path problem with CI on windows](http://www.cecilieo.com/techblog/path-problems-with-codeigniter-on-windows/)

Comment: Please check your PHP version and your error log . Refer to


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25675750/naming-convention-issues-when-using-codeigniter-in-windows-and-linux/25676012#25676012

Comment: In situations like this I usually place a die() statement in my default controller to see if it's reaching certain places.  I'd suggest you do that as it will help you narrow down where your code is breaking (probably  not the best, but those "blank" pages can be a real pain at times).  Recently moved from my local Windows enviornment to a linux enviornment and it was a folder capitalization issue.  Something to check.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comment by @Orangepill it could be either case sensitive unix filesystem either, in my own experience it was connected to the `.htaccess` parsed differently:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Sometimes these fail on linux as it requres an `?` sign after `index.php` so you can try:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

add .htaccess file and check controller and models name first letter required capital (in Linux)

.htaccess

```
 RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```